# Datastore Viewer - Server Error

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to use Datastore Viewer for one my app-id (vs-accounting)
Until today morning India time, it was working.    Now, for the past 2-3 hrs, I am getting the following error:

> Error: Server Error
>   The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after 1 day.

Answer (score 2):

I can see this too; this seems a problem with your datastore.  Please file a production ticket here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue